# Ajax call on POST with parameters doesn't work in WCF

Tags: jquery, ajax, wcf

My POST ajax call to WCF services does't work with parameters provided inside block,

```
 $("#btnPost").click(function(){
 //$.post("http://localhost:3700/TestService.svc/json_post/12345", //this works fine
        $.post("http://localhost:3700/TestService.svc/json_post",
        {
            id : "12345" // this is not working
        }, 
        function(data, status){

        alert("Data: " + data.DoWork_Result + "\nStatus: " + status);


        });
       });
```

Comment: If want to post a single parameter, use the uri, like in your example that works fine. You can post "data" when posting a complex object, like a class

Comment: is it inside $(document).ready(function(){ }); or end of page?

Comment: @RicardoPontual I added another parameter name, still same issue in the above code